# codemirror with javascript code inside it

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am having problem with codemirror http://codemirror.net/. When I type `<script>` inside the codemirror extra `script` is appended on `>` . For instance, I am writing `<script` as soon as I type `>` it becomes `<scriptscript>`. Has anyone gone through this problem too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(New user, so I can't add a comment.) Which mode are you using? I tried both http://codemirror.net/jstest.html and http://codemirror.net/mixedtest.html, but can't reproduce the problem. Also, which browser, and please check your error console for JS error messages.

Comment: i am using firefox and there is no js error messages. is it sufficient to add codes from http://codemirror.net/jstest.html and where to add them?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour when I forget to include "tokenizejavascript.js" in the parserfile option, so that's probably what you're doing.

Comment: I am also getting the similar type of problem.. may be this time also i missed out sth.. when I type my codes inside <script></script> tag, the code becomes invisible... say.. I add <script>console.log("hello world")</script> then the color of console.log("hello world") becomes black and I am not able to see it... any suggestions?